# Cannot run a python file from a windows ps1 file

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I have a ps1 file (named NPScript.ps1) with a simple function I'm using as a cmdlet within PowerShell (running windows 10).

```
function add-np() {
        Set-Location C:\Users\emers\Desktop\Code\Projects
        python.exe C:\Users\emers\Desktop\Code\mybin\NPPythonScript.py
    }
```

The first portion, the **Set-Location** portion, works just fine when I call ***add-np*** in PowerShell. I have a python script (NPPythonScript.py) that I want to execute as well when this function is called and that portion (see above) is not working it currently outputs nothing. The python file currently should just print ***"Hello!"***. When I run this:

```
python.exe C:\Users\emers\Desktop\Code\mybin\NPPythonScript.py
```

or this:

```
python C:\Users\emers\Desktop\Code\mybin\NPPythonScript.py
```

in PowerShell it works just fine and prints as it should. I've tried putting the full path to the python.exe with no luck. I tried a shebang line even though as far as I understand that is really for linux/OS contexts. Perhaps I wasn't implementing that correctly...? I saw a few other answers on here indicating that what I have should work if the location of the python.exe is in my Path, which it is. Since the line I have runs in PowerShell just fine and my function works for the other content within I just can't figure it out and I've been searching for an answer to my specific situation for hours now.

I'm calling the function by using the add-np cmdlet which is working just fine for the first portion of the function (the Set-Location portion).

At the suggestion of commenter VirtualScooter I've done a short intermediate test to see if the line runs when outside of the function so I reorganized like so:

```
python.exe C:\Users\emers\Desktop\Code\mybin\NPPythonScript.py

function add-np() {
    Set-Location C:\Users\emers\Desktop\Code\Projects
}
```

This does run as expected when I run the file in PowerShell and my function still works to move me into the projects folder when called.

Comment: Note that executing a `.ps1` file that contains a function definition only _defines_ that function, without actually _calling_ it.

Comment: I think you might want to consider one intermediate test: add a line with the `python.exe` run of the script in front of your function definition in the `.ps1` file to check that a straight run of your script works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to believe that the only thing that was wrong was that I hadn't properly restarted my terminal (Although I swore I had done that). Because this new code functions properly when the function is called and I've done essentially nothing different syntactically.

```
function New-project {
    Set-Location C:\Users\emers\Desktop\Code\Projects
    python.exe C:\Users\emers\Desktop\Code\mybin\NPPythonScript.py
}
```